# Is there a way to have blanks for null values in lineseries chart in wpf?

Tags: wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

Is there a way to have blanks for null values in lineseries chart in wpf?
I am using WPF toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

To answer as briefly as you asked, yes. See the [`BindingBase.FallbackValue` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.